# NestJS JWT Strategy: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, passport.js

I'm learning to create an authentication system with NestJS using JWT. My system has a CRUD for managing users but it can only be used by authenticated people, so I put this guard:

```js
@Controller('users')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
export class UsersController {
    \\ implementation
}
```

I'm trying to create the JWT strategy:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: this.config.get<string>('JWT_SECRET_PASS'),
    });
  }
}
```

But facing the error:

```
'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.
```

I need to access the ConfigService so I can define my secret which is in an env. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config` is passed as a parameter to the constructor, so you can remove the `this` in `this.config` and still access `config` just fine